# Make a generic C list to contain pointers

Tags: c, list

I have a generic list which works 100% and maintains:

```
/**
 * Generic List Container
 *
 * Implements a list container type.
 * The list his an internal iterator for external use. For all functions
 * where the state of the iterator after calling that function is not stated,
 * it is undefined. That is you cannot assume anything about it.
 *
 * The following functions are available:
 *
 *   listCreate               - Creates a new empty list
 *   listDestroy              - Deletes an existing list and frees all resources
 *   listCopy                 - Copies an existing list
 *   listGetSize              - Returns the size of a given list
 *   listFirst                - Sets the internal iterator to the first element
 *                              in the list, and returns it.
 *   listInsertFirst          - Inserts an element in the beginning of the list
 *   listInsertLast           - Inserts an element in the end of the list
 *   listInsertBeforeCurrent  - Inserts an element right before the place of
 *                              internal iterator
 *   listInsertAfterCurrent   - Inserts an element right after the place of the
 *                              internal iterator
 *   listRemoveCurrent        - Removes the element pointed by the internal
 *                              iterator
 *   listGetCurrent           - Return the current element (pointed by the 
 *                              internal iterator)
 *   listGetFirst             - Sets the internal iterator (also called current 
 *                              element) to be the first element in the list and 
 *                              return it.
 *   listGetNext              - Advances the list's iterator to the next element 
 *                              and return it 
 *   listSort                 - Sorts the list according to a given criteria
 *   listFilter               - Creates a copy of an existing list, filtered by
 *                              a boolean predicate
 *   listClear            - Clears all the data from the list
 */
```

and I provide

```
  /** Element data type for list container */
typedef void* ListElement;

/** Type of function for copying an element of the list */
typedef ListElement (*CopyListElement)(ListElement);

/** Type of function for deallocating an element of the list */
typedef void (*FreeListElement)(ListElement);

List listCreate(CopyListElement copyElement, FreeListElement freeElement);
```

Now, I want to use this list to hold pointers to data instead of the data itself. 
For example, I want a list of structs from the type

```
  struct CASH_element {
        int id;
        int passengers;
        int unpaidPassengers;
        bool reset;
        int profit;
    } Cash;

    struct Transportation_element {
        List cashes; //list of cashes
        int travels;
        int profit;
    };
```

so when I create the transportation type I use:

```
    Transportation* systemToAdd;
    systemToAdd->cashes = listCreate(cashCopy, DestroyCash);
    /* MORE CODE*/
```

Now, the interesting function is the copyElement function:

```
  void* cashCopy(void* cashCopy) {
    Cash* toCopy = (Cash*) cashCopy;
    if (toCopy == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    Cash* toAdd =  (Cash*) malloc(sizeof(*toAdd));
    if (toAdd == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    toAdd->id = toCopy->id;
    toAdd->passengers=toCopy->passengers;
    toAdd->unpaidPassengers = toCopy->unpaidPassengers;
    toAdd->reset=toCopy->reset;
    toAdd->unpaidPassengers=toCopy->unpaidPassengers;
    toAdd->profit=toCopy->profit;

    return  (Cash*)  toAdd;;
```

Obviously, this copies by value the Cash and all its data and once I update cash independently, the list node DOESN'T update. I want it to be updated. I guess I have to use pointers. I've tried modifiend the function but it fails:

```
  void* cashCopy(void* cashCopy) {

        return  (Cash*)&cashCopy;
   }

   and adding is straightforward:
     TransportationStatus trAddCash(Transportation* system, Cash c) {
        if (system == NULL) {
            return TR_FAIL;
        }
    Cash* cash=&c;
    if (LIST_SUCCESS != listInsertLast(system->cashes, cash)) {
        return TR_FAIL;
    }

    return TR_SUCCESS;

   }
```

There is a code sample which I want to work:

```
 cs1 = cashCreate(&c1, 123);
    Transportation trans1;
        TransportationStatus tr1;
    tr1=trCreate(&trans1);
    ASSERT_TEST(tr1==TR_SUCCESS);

    cs1 = cashTravel(&c1, &rq1, 660, "09/08/2011-02:51"); //THE FIRST TRAVEL
    tr1=trAddCash(&trans1,c1); //ADD THE CASH TO THE TRANSPORTATION STRUCT
    ASSERT_TEST(tr1==TR_SUCCESS);
    tr1=getTotalTravels(trans1, &result);
    ASSERT_TEST(result==1); //THAT'S OKAY BECAUSE TRAVEL BEFORE COPYING
    cs1 = cashTravel(&c1, &rq1, 660, "13/08/2011-02:51"); //THE SECOND TRAVEL
   tr1=getTotalTravels(trans1, &result);
   ASSERT_TEST(result==2); //FAIL!!!!
      cashTravel(listGetFirst(trans1.cashes),  &rq1, 660, "13/08/2010-02:51"); //TRAVEL WITH THE LIST   NODE
        tr1=getTotalTravels(trans1, &result);
  ASSERT_TEST(result==2); //SUCCESS!!!!
```

So basically, I would like to modify my copy function so I could update the node independently

Comment: Shrink your post. It contains too many details.

Comment: Also, *cash* is currency; a *cache*, on the other hand, is a temporary data storage area. Pretty sure you're creating *caches*, not *cashes* here.

Comment: actually it is a cash, as a cash register :)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work and what are the symptoms?

Comment: Are you wanting deep copy or shallow copy?  Are you wanting your list to hold Cash or Cash*?  If you are only storing pointers, then just store pointers, don't try to malloc or copy the contents of the pointers.  If you are storing Cash elements, then store Cash elements.

Comment: I'm trying to store a pointer so when the element changes, the list node will be updated along with it. I've tried to copy pointers in the copy function with   void* cashCopy(void* cashCopy) {
        return  (Cash*)&cashCopy;
   } but it doesn't work. I only managed to make it "work" with copying the elements itself, but then they aren't linked to the original and when the original one is updated, the list node doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Although your code "works," it is insanely complex.  Now you are discovering that "working" is not the primary virtue in code—you need to have something simple enough that when requirements change, you can change the code, or make new code.

Abandon this code entirely, and use what you have learned to make a *new* list module that you will easily be able to modify to hold pointers.

*Hint:* How will you know whose responsibility is is to `malloc` and `free` those pointers?

Comment: The generic list was actually supplied for me and it works perfectly well. The only thing I have to provide is a copy function and a destroy function. The list is efficient and tested, why would I want to build a new one? I treat it as an STL list. Just have to find what's wrong to use it to hold pointers. To build a new list would miss the point :) If I used the linux generic linked list, would it have been any better?

Comment: It's not insanely complex at all ... it's just a generic list container with a rich set of methods. @Jenny, you're way ahead of Norman; don't pay his uninformed criticism and non-answer any mind.

Comment: Jenny, I'm sure it works great.   The person who supplied it to you is insane, or possibly just inexperienced.  I'm sorry you're being asked to modify it.   Unfortunately dealing with gratuitous complexity is not always part of our mission here on StackOverflow.  But perhaps you will find people like @JimBalter who want to spend their time that way.